Is there a way to specify a salt in dart/flutter so I can use wordpress' salt?
I have a wordpress website. I am making a flutter/dart app.
I need to process logins, resetting of passwords, and sending of emails. I want to make sure this is secure.
I have had issues using the wordpress API via postman so I am thinking about using MySQL_Client: https://pub.dev/packages/mysql_client to connect to the database directly.
I also believe this will make the app faster so I don't have to connect through the wordpress website which can be slow.
I know the WP salt as it is in the wp-config.php file.. but I haven't been able to find a way to specify that same salt in dart/flutter so that I can retrieve the salted password and compare it to the one they enter (when logging in) and verify they are typing the correct password.
How would I go about doing this?
I have tried wp oauth plugins to go through the API and when I tried that I got a 400 bad request. I realize this means the request was malformed in some way I just don't understand how since I followed their instructions to a T. I was doing it all in postman to test the API before I fully went about it.
Supposedly there is a way to use the core API to login but I don't understand the docs so I don't know the endpoint or what is required to pass in order to use the core API. I tried asking on the WP stack exchange but they are unhelpful. Last question is still unanswered.

There are security risks to granting remote and direct connection access to a MySQL database. SQL injection, unauthorized changes, DoS attacks etc. Using API would be the best choice.

Alright, that's what I was thinking after thinking it over. Thank you!
